# Content-Type Text/HTML is not cached

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a simple situation. I am using jQuery's ajax method to get some data.

When I refer to "api.json" in url, I get proper response headers with etag, cache-control etc etc. The content-type is also "application/json"

But when I refer to a "api.php" in url, the response header changes, this time there is no etag, no cache-control and content-type is also "text/html" ( which is understood ).

In that php file the returned data is properly formatted using json_encode().

What I do not understand is, why etag and other caching headers are misbehaving?

How can I enable them to cache properly?

Comment: Apache, or whatever web server you're using, might set headers on a per filetype basis. Maybe they are only set for .json ending, or overridden for .php ending.

Comment: Set the appropriate headers you want

Comment: Any hints or links how?

Comment: PHP scripts don’t set caching headers by default – which makes sense, since usually their output _is_ dynamic and changes frequently. If you want caching headers for content output via a PHP script, you have to implement that yourself. (But then you have to also implement _checking_ for the corresponding request headers yourself – otherwise the script will just run through as usual, return all content, and send a 200 status code again.)

Answer (score 0):

The ETag header present in cross-origin responses will not be accessible to client-side code unless the server includes an Access-Control-Expose-Headers header in its response, with a value of "ETag". This is true of any "non-simple" response headers.

From [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

> 7.1.1 Handling a Response to a Cross-Origin Request User agents must filter out all response headers other than those that are a simple response header or of which the field name is an ASCII case-insensitive match for one of the values of the Access-Control-Expose-Headers headers (if any), before exposing response headers to APIs defined in CORS API specifications.

Simple response headers are limited to:

1. Cache-Control
2. Content-Language
3. Content-Type
4. Expires
5. Last-Modified
6. Pragma

All other headers that the client needs to access in the response must be "exposed" via the response header I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out but my problem is still unresolved. I used `header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag");` but it simply outputs the same line in header and not the orignal etag header.